# Jquery Ajax Post Symfony 500 internal Server Error:

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to use Ajax in Symfony with the next code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#area").append('');
                     $(function () {
                        $('.auditBtn').on('click',function(){
                             $area = $(this).attr('data-area');
                             $idAudit = $(this).attr('data-id');

                            var today = new Date();
                            var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                            var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                            today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
                            $("#area").append('<b> '+ $area+ '</b>');//$("#responsible").append('<b> '+ $responsible+ '</b>');
                            $("#startDate").append('<b> '+ today+ '</b>');
                            $("#idAudit").append('<b> '+$idAudit+'<b>');

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '{{ (path('questionsByAudit')) }}',
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    "idAudit":$idAudit
                                },
                                async: true,
                                success: function (data)
                                {
                                    console.log(data)
                                    alert("Funciona!!!");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
    </script>
```

The $idAudit is obtained of a modal.

this is my route:

```
questionsByAudit: 
    path: /QuestionsByAudit
    defaults: { _controller: FSABundle:FsaPlan/FsaPlanByAuditor:getQuestions }
    methods: [POST]
```

And this is my function in my controller:

```
 public function getQuestions(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $idAudit = $request->request->get('idAudit');
    $result = $em->getRepository('FSABundle:FsaAudits')
    ->findOneBy($idAudit);
    return $result;

}
```

But at the moment of click the button .auditBtn, I get the following error:

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

**Any idea or suggestion about how to fix it? Or what I'm doing wrong.**

Comment: A "server error" is an error in your *server* code, clearly. You're going to have to look at logs etc on the server to discover what's going wrong.

Comment: And how can I check them in Symfony?

Comment: nothing in /var/log/dev.log or /var/log/prod.log?